# Ayuda con Spring Security - Request method 'POST' not supported y como sacar ventana por defecto?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-security

Tengo dos problemas en uno, no sé si está bien postear los dos juntos pero creo que tienen relación uno con el otro así que ahí va:

Estoy intentando aplicar Spring Security en mi proyecto.

Lo primero que hice fue agregar estas dependencias en mi build.gradle file:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
compile 'org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:2.1.2.RELEASE'
```

Ahora cuando levanto la pagina me aparece un login por defecto donde debo ingresar una password de seguridad por defecto que me sale en la consola (siempre va cambiando, cada vez que levanto nuevamente la pagina).

OK ... luego siguiendo este tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ intenté de hacer otro login pero sin exito.

Dejo mi código:

**Clase MvcConfig:**

```
package WebSecurity;


@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements 

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home2").setViewName("home2");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureAsyncSupport(AsyncSupportConfigurer configurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {

    }

    @Override
    public void addReturnValueHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    }

    @Override
    public void configureHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {

    }

    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers) {

    }

    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public MessageCodesResolver getMessageCodesResolver() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Clase **WebSecurityConfig**

```
package WebSecurity;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // secret123
    private static final String ENCODED_PASSWORD = "$2a$10$AIUufK8g6EFhBcumRRV2L.AQNz3Bjp7oDQVFiO5JJMBFZQ6x2/R/2";


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .withUser("user")
                .password(ENCODED_PASSWORD)
                .roles("USER");
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

--------------- **Templates** -----------

**home2.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome!</h1>

<p>Click <a th:href="@{/hello}">here</a> to see a greeting.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**hello.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 th:inline="text">Hello [[${#httpServletRequest.remoteUser}]]!</h1>
<form th:action="@{/logout}" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Out"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <title>Spring Security Example </title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${param.error}">
    Invalid username and password.
</div>
<div th:if="${param.logout}">
    You have been logged out.
</div>
<form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
    <div><label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username"/> </label></div>
    <div><label> Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> </label></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Sign In"/></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y acá viene el problema ... cuando ingreso cualquier cosa en los inputs para loguearme me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo que pasa porque como dije estoy siguiendo un tutorial y copiando y pegando código, no es muy dificil. Mi segunda pregunta es como sacar el cartel de login que me aparece por defecto cada vez que levanto la pagina.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias a quien/es corresponda!!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que habilitar los métodos HTTP

En el `WebSecurityConfig` en `configure` coloca:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .authorizeRequests()

                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT).permitAll()
                        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and().formLogin().permitAll()
                        .and().logout().permitAll();

    }
```

Para tu otro problema, según entiendo, debes quitar el método loguin para que no pase el filtro del Websecurity. Ignorar el método
Has lo siguiente:

```
 @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/login",
        );
    }
```

Debes ajustar de acuerdo a la ubicación de tu servicio de loguin.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Cualquier cosa estoy pendiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias Miguel ... el método antMatchers() me sale en rojo, pero solo el primero, los demás me los reconoce ... ahora cuando borro el primero me pone el segundo en rojo ... raro ... dice "cannot resolve method antMatchers()" ... alguna idea ?

Comment: El segundo método tampoco me saca el cartel por defecto, sigue apareciendo :(

Comment: Discúlpame me faltó el .authorizeRequests(). Ya actualicé el código. Dale nuevamente por favor y me cuentas.

Comment: ahora lo q me pone en rojo es el  .authorizeRequests() ... no lo reconoce :(

Comment: Dale nuevamente, cambié el orden. Lo probé y funciona. Me cuentas ;)